# Any simple way to set one primary key as a foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, wamp

I have one table

`program(p_id(pk), program_name)`

and three other tables:

`graduate_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,program_name,session)`,

```
alumni_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,program_name,session),
```

`faculty_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,program_name,session)`...

I have to link the three tables with program table...How to link these tables in MySQL? `graduate_survey, alumni_survey`, faculty_survey are some forms which is calculated for some specific program...If in the forms `graduate_survey`, `alumni_survey`, `faculty_survey` there is no text box for entering the program_name, but if i made a column name 'program_name' in the database tables, can i enter the program_name by referencing to the `program` table? Is there will be any join query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the program id as foreign key in the other tables, like so:

```
program(p_id(pk), program_name)
graduate_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,p_id(fk),session), 
alumni_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,p_id(fk),session), 
faculty_survey(id(pk),PO1_avg,PO2_avg,p_id(fk),session)
```

You don't really need the program name for the sake of the FK constraints but it's still a nice to have at some point, maybe.

This way you can easily join based on p_id, for instance:

```
"SELECT * FROM program INNER JOIN graduate_survey ON program.p_id=graduate_survey.p_id WHERE <your condition here>"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To insert value in the graduate_survey after joining how to do that? is there will be insert-select operation?

Comment: The insert statement would look the same after the join. The join doesn't actually join the tables in the db, only in your query result. So an insert statement: 'INSERT INTO 'graduate survey'(`PO1_avg`, `PO2_avg`, `p_id`, 'session') VALUES ('x', 'y', 'z', 'xy')'

Comment: That means first i have to join the table...actually i am doing it in php so its a little bit confusing....let me try it..

Comment: Which part? Please detail what you are trying to do? Insert a program? Insert a new survey for a certain program? or something else?

Comment: suppose in the program table program_name is B.tech IT and p_id is 1. We fill up the survey forms for B.tech IT...Next the survey has done for another program say B.tech EE and p_id is 2...In the survey tables the foreign key p_id will refer to the pk of program table...Now if the B.tech IT again come to fill up the survey form then will the foreign key p_id of  the survey table refer to the p_id of B.tech IT which is 1?

Comment: Insert a new survey for a certain program what i am looking for.....and will the foreign key p_id in the survey_table be Auto Incremented?

Comment: _Now if the B.tech IT again come to fill up the survey form then will the foreign key p_id of the survey table refer to the p_id of B.tech IT which is 1_ Yes, that is correct. One program can have many surveys. You will have to find the p_id of the program that the survey is for and use that p_id when you insert into one of the survey tables. The FK p_id does not auto-increment but always has to be one of the p_id:s in the program table.

Comment: Now the question arise in my mind is there any query that foreign key p_id field automatically takes the p_id  of program table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145148/discussion-between-nge-and-debasish-choudhury).